# jQuery Grouping by first letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list of posts in Wordpress its looks like this:

```
<div class="products uk-grid uk-grid-width-medium-1-4">
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>AShape(14)</h3></a>
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>AShape(20)</h3></a>
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>CShape(38)</h3></a>
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>FShape(1)</h3></a>
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>FShape(4)</h3></a>
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>ZShape(2)</h3></a> 
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>ZShape(24)</h3></a> 
</div>
```

I need to find some way to pass all links through script and transform it in letter groups. So it should take first letter from all `<h3>` of links and make groups like this:

```
<div class="products uk-grid uk-grid-width-medium-1-4">
  <div>
    <span>A</span>
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>AShape(14)</h3></a>
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>AShape(20)</h3></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>C</span>
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>CShape(38)</h3></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>F</span>
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>FShape(1)</h3></a>
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>FShape(4)</h3></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Z</span>
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>ZShape(2)</h3></a> 
    <a href="#custom-url"><h3>ZShape(24)</h3></a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

How i can do it using jQuery?
here i have simple codepen: http://codepen.io/ponciusz/pen/EPgQKP

Comment: As a random side note, i'd suggest putting the anchor elements inside of the `h3` elements..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate over each of the children elements and create corresponding containers for each letter. In the example below, a `div` container is appending with a custom `data-letter` attribute if a container does not already exist for that letter.

As I mentioned in the comments, I'd also suggest placing the `a` element inside of the `h3` elements as well:

```js
$('.products > h3').each(function () {
  var letter = $('a', this).text().charAt(0);
  
  if (!$(this).parent().find('[data-letter="'+ letter +'"]').length) {
    $(this).parent().append('<div data-letter="'+ letter+'"><span>'+ letter +'</span></div>');
  }
  $(this).parent().find('[data-letter="'+ letter +'"]').append(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="products uk-grid uk-grid-width-medium-1-4">
    <h3><a href="#custom-url">AShape(14)</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="#custom-url">AShape(20)</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="#custom-url">CShape(38)</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="#custom-url">FShape(1)</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="#custom-url">FShape(4)</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="#custom-url">ZShape(2)</a></h3> 
    <h3><a href="#custom-url">ZShape(24)</a></h3> 
</div>
```

Comment: I can't understand why You use '.length' is it like checking 'if exist'?

Comment: @Ponciusz Yep, exactly. A jQuery object is similar to an array, so in this case I am checking if the element doesn't exist (`!$(...).length`) and then appending the container.