# How to group a list by first letter?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a list and I need to make something like that:

A.

```
Andrei


Andreea
```

B.

```
Bogdan

Borris
```

etc.

So, now I have a JavaScript which ordering alphabetically my list, but I don't know how to insert that function with first letter.Can you help me with that please?

Here is my code:

```
     <ul style="list-style: none;right: 40px; position: relative" id="destPopuler">
           @foreach($users->contact as $user)

                     @if( $user->role[0]->pivot->role_id == 1 )
           <li class="country"><input class="my_div" id="{{$user->username}}" name="target_id[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $user->id }}" <?php if(isset($replyMessage)){ if($replyMessage == $user->id) { echo "checked"; } } ?>><span style="padding: 5px" class="name">{{ $user->username }}</span></li>
                     @endif

                 @endforeach
</ul>

function sortList(ul) {
  var ul = document.getElementById(ul);

  Array.from(ul.getElementsByTagName("LI"))
    .sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent))
    .forEach(li => ul.appendChild(li));
}

sortList("destPopuler");
```

Here is something like I want : [jQuery Grouping by first letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467094/jquery-grouping-by-first-letter) , but I don't know how exactly to insert it based on my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide this on Laravel side -

```
 ... public function users() 
     {
         $users = Users::all();

         $groupedUsers = $users->groupBy(function($item,$key) {
             return $item->username[0]; 
         })->sortBy(function($item,$key){      
             return $key;
         });

         return view('users', ['users' => $groupedUsers]);
     }
```

Or, if you want use your function, you can put your js code in section for javascript:

In your layout you should include -

```
      @yield('js')
```

And in your view -

```
      @section('js')
         // your js function
      @endsection
```